# Is the constructor of a temporary object guaranteed to happen before any arguments to a member function called on it are evaluated?

Tags: c++

If I have a macro like

```
#define ABORT(msg) AbortHelper(__FILE__, __LINE__).Report(msg)
```

Is `AbortHelper::AbortHelper(const char*, long)` guaranteed to be called before `msg` is evaluated? This matters because I want to ensure that if a statement like `ABORT(GenerateAbortMsg());` is evaluated, the program will abort at that line, even if `GenerateAbortMsg()` throws an exception (implemented by having `AbortHelper::~AbortHelper` call `abort` or equivalent).

I'm interested in the answer for all versions of the C++ standard (if they differ)

Comment: No.    In usage like `ABORT(message);`, which expands to  `AbortHelper(__FILE__, __LINE__).Report(message);`  the sequencing of calling the constructor and evaluating `message` is unspecified.    It is guaranteed that `Report()` will be called after both the constructor is called and `message` is evaluated, but that doesn't impose any constraints on how `message` and the constructor call are sequenced relative to each other.

Comment: @TheNomad It was just an example, in my actual code the macro takes printf-style arguments and is used in various different places with various different arguments, and I was worried about it being used in, for example, low-memory situations where generating the abort message may itself require memory allocation.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll delete it to not make it more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cppreference.com's summary of [evaluation ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) rules is straightforward enough to answer this.

Pre-C++11 sequence point-based rule do not give you any guarantees here. The only sequence points here are the one at the end of the full expression, and between the evaluation of the function call arguments and the function call, and when returning from the function (with respect to the returned value).

The sequence point-based rules do not, otherwise, specify any particular evaluation order of the full expression. Different parts of the full expression can be evaluated in any order.

The sequence-before rules for C++11, and going forward, do not give you any hope either. With respect to function calls they are similar to pre-C++11 rules, specifying functionally similar rules with respect to function parameter evaluation, the function call itself, and the function's returned value.

TLDR: nope.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that page, but was hoping I was missing something.

Comment: Bullet 13 in the link applies since C++17.

Answer (score 6):

Before C++17 there is no such guarantee.

Since C++17 it is guaranteed that `AbortHelper(__FILE__, __LINE__).Report` is *sequenced-before*, i.e. fully evaluated before, evaluation of `msg`. That includes the temporary materialization and constructor call. Generally in C++17, the postfix expression of a function call is sequenced before any expressions in the the function arguments.

This change for C++17 was made specifically because it is so easy to  mistakenly rely on this order of evaluation in chained member function calls implicitly that even the inventor of C++ made this mistake in one of the top C++ books without anyone noticing it for a long time. See the rational in [P0145](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf).

Comment: Good to know (and makes sense to me, I just assumed it would be the case), unfortunately I still have to support C++11 for the foreseeable future.